# NetBeans + GlassFish application does not see the table from database

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

I have a problem with visibility of a table in my database.
I am trying to write an example project from book "Java How To Program 9th edition" from chapter JavaServer Faces and I have completed everything without any errors, but my web application does not see my table.

[image: servicetab in netbeans]
<sub>(source: [www.iv.pl](http://www.iv.pl/images/98495825713921260154.png))</sub>

As you can see I have a table where it should be (with the name ADRESY).
Here is my code with the SQL Query.

```
public ResultSet getAddresses() throws SQLException{
    if(dataSource == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to obtain DataSource");
    
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    if(connection == null)
        throw new SQLException("Unable to connect to DataSource");
    
    try{
        PreparedStatement getAddresses = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, STREET, CITY, STATE, ZIP " +
                "FROM ADRESY ORDER BY LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME");
        CachedRowSet rowSet = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowSet.populate(getAddresses.executeQuery());
        return rowSet;
    }finally{
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

And before that I have annotation:

```
@Resource ( name="jdbc/addressbook" )
DataSource dataSource;
```

There are no errors, but when I'm running page that uses this statement I have an Error:

> An Error Occurred:
>
> Table/view 'ADRESY' does not exist.

And screen with resources:
[image: resources glassfish]
<sub>(source: [www.iv.pl](http://www.iv.pl/images/77706421595933269755.png))</sub>

And as requested (not sure if that's what you wanted):
[image: resource jndi name]

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/addressbook</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

I didn't have the `<resource-ref>` tag before, I added it a moment ago, but it still doesn't work. And I think I don't have glassfish-resources.xml file.

And I checked this driver and here's next screenshot:
[image: connection pool driver]
<sub>(source: [www.iv.pl](http://www.iv.pl/images/78467121145061967972.png))</sub>

Driver classname is empty but when I created the connection pool I selected Java DB as driver vendor. I don't know if it should look like that or not...

Comment: Did you really create a JDBC resource named addressbook?

Comment: Yep, I edited my post with a screenshot

Comment: What's the driver of your JDBC Connection pool `AddressBookPool` ? Please post the configuration files (such as web.xml and/or glassfish-resources.xml) which are in your project folder.

Comment: So I added few things to my first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I think I don't have glassfish-resources.xml file.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/pongegf-1517943.html

> Application-scoped resources are declared as part of a file called
>   glassfish-resources.xml. In the case of a WAR deployment, the file is
>   placed in WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.

You may also want to try pinging your pool. You have a 'ping' button in the left top corner of the 'EDIT JDBC connection Pool' screen. See your screenshot.

Comment: I have pinged the pool several times and it was succesfull, so it's not that. But I have read this link you gave me, I didn't have this xml file but I created it, and added resource reference and it works now, so thank you very much!